# Trigger Not Firing When Condition is Based on Custom Event Picklist Field

Tags: trigger, custom-field, account, event

I am trying to update a custom date field on the Account object when an event of a specific type is created.  The Event UI includes a custom type field called Type__c, and the picklist value from this field is the value I want to use in my trigger logic.  However, when I include this logic in the if statement (line 11) the condition does not resolve to True, so the code setting the custom date field on Account does not execute.

I have run the SOQL query for Event.Type__c = 'Custom Type 1' and I get expected records returned.  However, the trigger fails to update the Account field.

If I comment out this line, the trigger completes and the date field on Account is updated.

What am I missing?

I tested a very similar trigger in a different org, but utilized the standard Event.type field, and it worked as expected.  I'm stumped.

```
trigger onService on Account (before insert, before update) {

    for (Account act : Trigger.new) {

        // force null value to On_Service_Date__c to zero if event deleted
        act.Custom_Date__c  = null;
        // Search for related events WHERE Account Id = act.Id
        List<Event> evt         =   [SELECT Id, Subject, WhatId, Type__c, StartDateTime FROM Event
                                    WHERE WhatId = :act.Id];
        // Filter results for only Events of type ID / Transition ID
        for (Event e :evt) {

            if (e.Type__c == 'Custom Type 1' || e.Type__c == 'Custom Type 2') {

                if(e.StartDateTime <= datetime.now()) {

                    act.Custom_Date__c = e.StartDateTime;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) this trigger needs to be bulkified and should not see production in its current state; (2) is `Custom Type 1` the picklist API value or label?; (3) are you running _equivalent_ queries in the Developer Console? There's several filters in place here in both SOQL and Apex, which I'd recommend reducing to just a SOQL query.

Comment: 1. Understood.

2. Custom Type 1 is the picklist value.

3. The Query I ran was:

SELECT AccountId, Type__c FROM Event WHERE Type__c = 'Custom Type 1' OR Type__c = 'Custom Type 2'

It returned both records I was looking for, one where the event type was Custom Type 1 and one where the event type was Custom Type 2.